(MASM615, DOSBOX 0.74-3) Video programming and graphics
I haven't been taught much in this course other than calculators and printing pixels, and pretty much have been thrown into this. I need to create a game in MASM615 with their interrupts (without the use of irvine32.inc as 32 bit architecture cannot be run on DOSBOX, irvine16.inc may be used). I need to print BOOKCLUB in cyan and two options for the user to select using the enter button which will then redirect to a different screen. Here's the code I have worked on so far:
.model small
.stack 100h
.data

charB db 3Eh, 22h, 22h, 3Ch, 22h, 22h, 3Eh, 00h  ; Bitmap for 'B'
charO db 1Ch, 22h, 22h, 22h, 22h, 22h, 1Ch, 00h  ; Bitmap for 'O'
charK db 22h, 24h, 28h, 30h, 28h, 24h, 22h, 00h  ; Bitmap for 'K'
charC db 1Eh, 22h, 20h, 20h, 20h, 22h, 1Eh, 00h  ; Bitmap for 'C'
charL db 20h, 20h, 20h, 20h, 20h, 20h, 3Eh, 00h  ; Bitmap for 'L'
charU db 24h, 24h, 24h, 24h, 24h, 24h, 18h, 00h  ; Bitmap for 'U'

message db "BOOKCLUB$"

.code
main proc
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    
    mov ax, 13h
    int 10h

    mov ax, 0A000h
    mov es, ax

    mov bx, 60          ; Starting position X
    mov dx, 100         ; Starting position Y
    mov si, offset message
    call PrintString

    ;wait for keypress
    mov ah, 00h
    int 16h

    ;Return to text mode
    mov ax, 0003h
    int 10h

    mov ax, 4Ch
    int 21h
main endp

PrintString proc
    print_loop:
        lodsb               ; Load byte from SI into AL, increments SI
        cmp al, '$'         ; Check if the character is '$' (end of string)
        je print_done       ; Jump if end of string
        call PrintChar
        add bx, 8           ; Move to the next character position on X
        jmp print_loop      ; Continue loop
    print_done:
    ret
PrintString endp

PrintChar proc
    cmp al, 'B'
    je printB
    cmp al, 'O'
    je printO
    cmp al, 'K'
    je printK
    cmp al, 'C'
    je printC
    cmp al, 'L'
    je printL
    cmp al, 'U'
    je printU
    cmp al, 'B'
    je printB
    ret

printB:  mov si, offset charB
    jmp print
printO:  mov si, offset charO
    jmp print
printK:  mov si, offset charK
    jmp print
printC:  mov si, offset charC
    jmp print
printL:  mov si, offset charL
    jmp print
printU:  mov si, offset charU
    jmp print

print:
    push ax
    push bx
    push cx
    push dx
    push di
    mov cx, 8  ; Number of rows
draw_row:
    mov al, [si]
    mov bl, 8  ; Number of bits
draw_pixel:
    test al, 80h ; Check the highest bit
    jz skip_pixel
    ; Set pixel at (di, dx) to Cyan (color index 03h)
    mov ax, dx
    mov di, ax
    mov al, 03h  ; Cyan color
    stosb
skip_pixel:
    shl al, 1    ; Shift to the next bit
    inc di       ; Move to the next pixel on the same row
    dec bl
    jnz draw_pixel
    inc si       ; Move to the next byte in bitmap
    add dx, 320  ; Move to the start of the next line
    sub di, 8    ; Adjust X position back
    dec cx
    jnz draw_row
    pop di
    pop dx
    pop cx
    pop bx
    pop ax
    ret
PrintChar endp
end main

Whenever I try doing this on my own, I am always met with a syntax error or an error that tells me I am doing something wrong without emphasising what I'm doing wrong. I need to print BOOKCLUB in CYAN letter by letter. The only thing printing is a cyan horizontal small line on the top of the screen. I would also appreciate resources for this type of task.
